# How to enable specific dates only on AngularJs datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, date, datepicker

How can I get specific list of date clickable on AngularJs datepicker. I follow the link  http://plnkr.co/edit/gGAU0L?p=preview Here weekends are disabled. I think this function can be modified for enable instead of disable.

```
// Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };
```

Actually I'm working on a patient care project where patient must have to click dates that are available for doctor. Xperts Plz help me........thanx

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further on what you are trying to do? Your question is a little unclear!

Comment: I just need a ng calendar where doctor's available dates will be clickable by patient when getting doctor's appointment. so if I have dates in dateList of doctor's available dates how can I enable only that dates on the datepicker ui as the http://plnkr.co/edit/gGAU0L?p=preview :) thnx JMK

Comment: Did you get a change to figure out with this? 'cause I have same problem and can't find an aswer or example. Thanks!

Comment: ya I got solved this with my won way, I'll provide you a plunkr within consecutive hours, thankz

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use this function to make specific dates (non-)clickable. Just return `true` or `false`, based on a request or whatever your criteria is:

```
// Disable specific dates
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    // return true or false here
};
```

Comment: I've a doctor's available date array, I want know how to access the 'date' object with the date list and enable that dates on calender UI. Thnx @DonJuwe, plz give me more specific way that I can solve my problem

Comment: Hi Sharif! please upload your plunker. it will be very helpful! the full code as an answer would be appreciated where you enable the dates you want!